how can I change date in jet engine's script
I want to change date from AD date to solar date in the WordPress of the plugin file editor.
In which plugin file I can do this ?
I looked for the file jet_engine.php but I didn't understand how to change it .
Some people said that it is impossible to do this because the plugin is not original, but I use the original version

Add Custom Code in functions.php:
add_filter('jet-engine/listings/dynamic-field/date', 'convert_to_jalali_date', 10, 3);

function convert_to_jalali_date($output, $settings, $field) {
    if (!empty($field) && $field['type'] == 'date') {
        $output = jdate('Y/m/d', strtotime($output)); // Convert to Jalali date
    }
    return $output;
}


Install WP-Jalali plugin for Jalali date conversion.
Add a filter in your theme’s functions.php to convert JetEngine dates using jdate().

